# Getting dates for past month period Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have to aggregate some financial data for past month period. For example, if today is March, 14, I need to get financial data from February, 01 to February, 28.
If today is April, 20, I need to get financial data from March, 01 to March, 31.
I have a function that takes two parameters: date_from & date_to (in %Y-%m-%d format).
I can get the data from last 30 days, but I need the data from past month period

```
# getting last 30 days
def get_analytics_time_interval() -> tuple:
    tz = pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
    now = datetime.now(tz)
    from_date = now - timedelta(days=31)
    to_date = now + timedelta(days=1)
    return from_date, to_date

intervals = get_analytics_time_interval()

# getting financial data
def get_sold_products(date_from=intervals[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                       date_to=intervals[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

So, I don't know if Python have a built-in functionality that allows to get the first and the last days of past month. If there is not one, how can I solve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just take off today's day-of-month to get the last day of the previous month. Then replace that day with 1 to get the 1st.

Also, if you don't care about the time as it appears in your example, it's probably easier to use the date type instead of datetime.

```
from typing import Tuple
from datetime import date, timedelta


def get_previous_month() -> Tuple[date, date]:
    today = date.today()
    to_date = today - timedelta(days=today.day)
    from_date = to_date.replace(day=1)
    return from_date, to_date


print(*get_previous_month())
# 2023-02-01 2023-02-28
```